# Is there a way to show that $\sum \frac{1}{1+k}$ diverges using PGF?

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series

Given a random variable $X$ such that $\operatorname{Pr}(X=k)=\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$, I consider the probability generating function $\mathbb{E}(t^X)=\sum \frac{t^k}{k}-\frac{t^k}{k+1}$.

Somehow using PGFs, I would like to show that the expectation is not finite.

> Show that $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is not finite

Just from the definition of expectation, I noted that the series $\frac{1}{k+1}$ diverges as it is practically harmonic, but my exercise hints that there may be another way to show this using the PGF.

Only property that I think that may be of some help might be that the derivative of a PGF (as a function of $t$) evaluated at $t=1$ is equal to the expectation.

If I go with this route, then taking the derivative of my two terms in my series, I get that $\frac{d}{dt} (\frac{t^k}{k}-\frac{t^k}{k+1})=\frac{1}{k}t^k\ln(t)-\frac{1}{k+1} t^k \ln t$, but I'm not sure if this series is divergent?

Even if I wanted to just plug in $t=1$ into the derivative that I obtained, I would have $\ln(1)=0$, which would mean the expectation is in fact finite?

ignore this part: (I had the exponent for $t$ as "X" instead of "k"
Factoring the $t^X \ln(t)$ out gives just $\sum \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$, which telescopes to the value of $1$, so I'm just left with $t^k \ln(t)$, but I'm not sure if this is a) the proper way to attempt this problem, or b) even if this is the right way, how to determine if that last term diverges.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: The terms in your sum ought to be $t^k$ rather than $t^X$.

Comment: No. It is $t^{k-1}-(k+1)t^k$.

Comment: $E(X)=\lim_{t\to 1-}(E(t^X))'=\lim_{t\to 1-}(\log(1+t)-\frac 1 t(\log(1+t)-t))'=\dots$